# Is it okay to frequently use custom variables for Spring Entity?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, entity

I learned Entity as an object that matches 1:1 with a column.

And I understood that "other fields or objects" should not come except for columns that match 1:1.

However, when such content was needed, a lot of unnecessary code or new objects were needed to keep the content.

I thought something was wrong, so I looked it up, and there was an annotation called @Transient .

Looking at the purpose, it didn't seem to matter to create custom (not in DB) fields in the Entity.

Is my understanding correct?

Is there any problem if I create and use the fields I want (not in the DB) in the Entity?

Comment: It sounds like you have understood correctly. What is proper and improper use of `@Transient` is debatable and opinion-based, so not really a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't know the exact intent of your comment.

Is it intended that there is no problem in using additional fields for Entity and that it is correct?

Comment: What is the purpose of those fields in your entities that you have (or want to be) marked as `@Transient`? It looks like you're trying to use those entities outside the scope of data access (probably as DTOs) which is not a good design.

Comment: The purpose of use is simple. As an example, suppose you have a userEntity with fields id, password, and birthDay.

Here, I'll process birthDay to get age.

The current entity does not have an age. So, add an age field to the Entity and complete the Entity by including it. Finally, it creates a DTO with Entity as a parameter and returns a DTO consisting of id, birthDay, and age, excluding password.

Comment: Of course, I can immediately create a DTO with age. However, in the structure I think, it takes priority to return an Entity.

Comment: That’s possible if you want to design it that way. Common recommendations would be to avoid redundancy and just add a method that calculates the age on request.